# Замена элементов вложенного списка по словарю Python.

Tags: python, list

Есть вложенные списки. Нужно заменить элемент с индексом 0 каждого вложенного списка на значение ключа в словаре, если ключ совпадает.

```
l = [[1, [1, 'spam']], [1, [2, 'ham']], [1, [2, 'eggs']], [2, [2, 'coffee']]]
d = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
```

Должно получиться:

```
l = [[one, [1, 'spam']], [one, [2, 'ham']], [one, [2, 'eggs']], [two, [2, 'coffee']]]
```

Comment: И что конкретно не получается?

Comment: В простых списках все просто:
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}


for index, item in enumerate(a):
    if item in b:
        a[index] = b[item]

print a

А как во вложенных добраться до элемента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k, v = zip(*l)
new_l = zip(map(lambda x: d[x] if x in d else x, k), v)
```

Comment: Можно и смешнее

     new_l = map (lambda s: s[0] in d and [d[s[0]], s[1]] or s, l)

Comment: Вариант @alexlz круче. Он охватывает ещё и случаи когда размеры списков второго уровня не статичны. Например,

    l = [[one, [1, 'spam'], 'bla-bla-bla'], [one, [2, 'ham']], [one, [2, 'eggs']], [two, [2, 'coffee']]]

Comment: А возможно проще, без использования lambda?

Comment: Вот без lambda:

    def key_or_self(x):
        return d[x] of x in d else x

    k, v = zip(*l)
    new_l = zip(map(key_or_self, k), v)

Answer (score 0):

я бы сделал так.

Разбил бы ваш большой список на маленькие

for i in l:

первая команда выдала бы мне i=[1, [1, 'spam']]

и заменил бы тут ваш нулевой символ

ну а далее думаю уже и сами понимаете что делать.